# Lag/delay from one activity to another with flags CLEAR_TASK/NEW_TASK

Tags: android

I have two activities, A1, A2.

When I go from A1 ---> A2, I dont want A1 on activity stack, so I use following code in A1

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(A2)
    finish();
```

However there is a a lag/delay when I go from A1->A2. Lag means there is blank screen for a second or two.

When I dont use the flags, there is no lag/delay. But, I can go A2 --> A1 that I dont want.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there some way, I can remove the lag/delay?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than killing your old activity programatically when you start your new activity you should instead be marking it with the "noHistory" flag in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">
        // intent filters and other crap
    </activity>
```

To find out more about this attribute search (ctrl-f, not search the website) for "history" on the [google android docs here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Thank you. I upvote as finish was unavoidable for me. But I did use android:noHistory.

Comment: Cool, thank you! Just curious, did this help to speed up the start of the second activity?

Comment: lag was gone due to flags removal. But no_history seemed like the right thing to do. So, I used it.